# EXT JS 4.1 how to display a grid in tabPanel

Tags: extjs, grid, tabpanel

I am trying to display a grid (object Ext.grid.GridPanel of EXTJS 4.1) in a tabPanel (object Ext.tab.Panel) but I have problems : the grid works perfectly as an independant source code, and the panel works also as an independant source code.
But when I try to make the grid and the panel working together, it doesn't work.

Grid :

```
 var monGridPanelDetailEcriture = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'monGridPanelDetailEcriture',
    frame: true,
    width: 1100,
    autoHeight: true,
    renderTo: 'gridDetailEcriture',
    store: monStoreDetailEcriture,
    columns: mesColonnesDetailEcriture
});
```

TabPanel :

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width: 450,
    activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
    defaults :{
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Short Text',
        closable: true
    },{
        title: 'Long Text'
    }]
});
```

I search on internet for a solution but each time what I found didn't work :
I tried this solution which was explained on several forums :

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width: 450,
    activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
    defaults :{
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    items: [{
        monGridPanelDetailEcriture 
    },{
        title: 'Long Text'
    }]
});
```

But I have a Javascript error indicating this is not a way to describe items.

I also tried to create a new type of widget on the Grid (with the property "alias") but it didn't work.

Do someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt is almost there but `monGridPanelDetailEcriture` is already an object do you don't need to wrap it in {}.

Therefore the following should work:

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width: 450,
    activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
    defaults :{
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    items: [
        monGridPanelDetailEcriture
    ]
});
```

EDIT: You probably also don't want the renderTo on your grid, as that will be rendering within you tab panel.
EDIT-EDIT: Also, I think it's perhaps better practice to use Ext.getBody() in your renderTo, rather then document.body. Seems a bit more Ext'y

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly !! And thank you for your advice I'm going to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Tabs:

```
 var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {

     renderTo: document.body,
     width: 450,
     activeTab: 0,     // first tab initially active
     defaults :{
          bodyPadding: 10
      },
    items: [
          monGridPanelDetailEcriture,
          {
           title:'tab2',
           html:'I m tab 2'
           }
       ]
   });
```